# I am looking to run a django server on my personal PC that can be available through WAN

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a developmental website and I need to be able to move it to a public domain, so I went and made the purchase of a domain and now i want to make the django app i have written publically available without purchasing a web hosting service quite yet or I might plan on investing in an actually windows server, if anyone knows how to go about doing this purely for developmental use and proff of concept practice, it would be great to see a video or a step by step guide.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad question, so I will break it down for you in bits.

Your domain name has 'DNS records'. There are several types but the one you are looking for is the an A record. This type of DNS record points the 'domain.com' to an IP adress. The IP adress needs to be your external IP (can be found by going to api.ipify.org for example). This will make sure that when people on the internet will go to 'domain.com', the traffic is routed to you.

Then, on your own router, you will probably need to configure a NAT rule (e.g. all incoming traffic on port 80 needs to be routed to local IP:80 <ip_adress_of_your_computer>). Often this is called 'port forwarding' on your router, but that depends on the model you have.

After that, your web app is available through your domain name. Note that this is only very basic and does not take into account SSL (https).

Comment: Do you have a website that can take into account SSL for use at a later date?